# How can I Validate my form using class only?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have radio buttons that has a same class.

and this radio buttons is dynamic, that's why I am thinking on using the class for validation.

Here is my code.

```js
$('#listening_choices_wrapper').on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $(".validation_radio").each(function() {

    });

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<form id="listening_choices_wrapper">
   <div class="listening_question_scenario">
      <p id="display_question_scenario">
         1. Question 1?
      </p>
   </div>
   <div id="question_choices" class="listening_question_choice">
      <input type="radio" class="validation_radio" name="answer_choice_0" value="17">
      <label>Test 1</label>
      <input type="radio" class="validation_radio" name="answer_choice_0" value="18">
      <label>Test 2</label>
      <input type="radio" class="validation_radio" name="answer_choice_0" value="19">
      <label>Test 3</label>
      <input type="radio" class="validation_radio" name="answer_choice_0" value="20">
      <label>Test 4</label>
   </div>
   <div class="listening_question_scenario">
      <p id="display_question_scenario">
         2. Question 2?
      </p>
   </div>
   <div id="question_choices" class="listening_question_choice">
      <input type="radio" class="validation_radio" name="answer_choice_1" value="17">
      <label>Test 5</label>
      <input type="radio" class="validation_radio" name="answer_choice_1" value="18">
      <label>Test 6</label>
      <input type="radio" class="validation_radio" name="answer_choice_1" value="19">
      <label>Test 7</label>
      <input type="radio" class="validation_radio" name="answer_choice_1" value="20">
      <label>Test 8</label>
   </div>

  <button type="submit" class="btn">Submit</button>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

How can I validate them? so that the user can't submit it.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Check whether each question has a selected radio button. If not then call `preventDefault()`.

Comment: How can i do that sir?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest that you wrap each bank of answers in a `fieldset` element, and put the class on that. You can then iterate over those with each (as you did in your code) and look to see whether there are no `input` elements that are `:checked`

```
if($(this).find("input:checked").length == 0){
  // no answer given
}
```

You can then also use some sort of label to improve the message to the user - and if any answers missed only then call `e.preventDefault()`.

Live example below:

```js
$('#listening_choices_wrapper').on('submit', function(e) {
    
    var missingAnswers = [];
    $(".validation_radio").each(function() {
      if($(this).find("input:checked").length == 0){
        missingAnswers.push($(this).data("label"));
      }
    });
    
    if(missingAnswers.length > 0){
      e.preventDefault();
      alert(`You are missing answers to: ${missingAnswers}`)
    }

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<form id="listening_choices_wrapper">
   <div class="listening_question_scenario">
      <p id="display_question_scenario">
         1. Question 1?
      </p>
   </div>
   <div id="question_choices" class="listening_question_choice">
     <fieldset class="validation_radio" data-label="answer1">
        <input type="radio" name="answer_choice_0" value="17">
        <label>Test 1</label>
        <input type="radio" name="answer_choice_0" value="18">
        <label>Test 2</label>
        <input type="radio" name="answer_choice_0" value="19">
        <label>Test 3</label>
        <input type="radio" name="answer_choice_0" value="20">
        <label>Test 4</label>
      </fieldset>
   </div>
   <div class="listening_question_scenario">
      <p id="display_question_scenario">
         2. Question 2?
      </p>
   </div>
   <div id="question_choices" class="listening_question_choice">
      <fieldset class="validation_radio" data-label="answer2">
        <input type="radio" name="answer_choice_1" value="17">
        <label>Test 5</label>
        <input type="radio" name="answer_choice_1" value="18">
        <label>Test 6</label>
        <input type="radio" name="answer_choice_1" value="19">
        <label>Test 7</label>
        <input type="radio" name="answer_choice_1" value="20">
        <label>Test 8</label>
      </fieldset>
   </div>

  <button type="submit" class="btn">Submit</button>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think  this is the solution on my problem sir, I will just implement it to my code. thank you very much sir.

Answer (score 1):

You can add the `required` attribute to all the input tags for native browser validation:

```
<div id="question_choices" class="listening_question_choice">
  <input type="radio" class="validation_radio" name="answer_choice_0" value="17" required>
  <label>Test 1</label>
  <input type="radio" class="validation_radio" name="answer_choice_0" value="18" required>
  <label>Test 2</label>
  <input type="radio" class="validation_radio" name="answer_choice_0" value="19" required>
  <label>Test 3</label>
  <input type="radio" class="validation_radio" name="answer_choice_0" value="20" required>
  <label>Test 4</label>
</div>
```

But to answer your question, I wrote this jQuery script:

```
$('#listening_choices_wrapper').on('submit', function(e) {
    $('.error').remove()
    e.preventDefault();
    
    $('.listening_question_choice').each((i, e) => {
        let valid = false
        $(e).find('.validation_radio').each((i ,e) => {
            if($(e).prop("checked")) {
                valid = true
            }
        })
        if (!valid) {
            $(e).append('<div class="error" style="color: red;">Error: this radio is required!</div>')
        }
    })
});
```

I hope this helps!